# Add additional model to model hook triggered from link-to

Tags: ember.js

I'm happy that multiple models can be loaded into a route using something like this (although feel free to correct if there's a better way!):

```
 model: function() {
        var self = this;
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            foos: self.store.find('foos'),
            bars: self.store.find('bars'),
        });
```

However, if the model hook is set by a model being passed by, for example, a link-to helper, how should I add the additional model?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

So in my case I have a **unit** and **objective**, which are related. A **unit** can have many **objectives** - although its a one way relationship.

In my **units** route, I click on a **unit** which links-to **units/unit:ID** route. So the **unit** is set as the model, but I also want all **objectives** loaded into the model, so that I can select and add these to the **unit**.

Comment: If you are using information being passed by a `link-to` helper in your `Route`, then how will you rebuild the route with going through the `link-to`?  In other words, if I just refresh the screen, is there enough information in the URL (including queryParams) to build the `Route` model?

Comment: To clarify my comment, please see [this page](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/routing/#toc_routing).  A quote: `In Ember.js, each of the possible states in your application is represented by a URL. Because all of the questions we asked above— Are we logged in? What post are we looking at? —are encapsulated by route handlers for the URLs, answering them is both simple and accurate.`

Comment: You'll have to forgive me, I'm still learning here. Does my edit answer your question? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not everything in your page must be in the route's `model`.  For example, you may have a `Route` that contains a `Unit` object.  To get a list of all `Objective` objects, you could add a simple property to your `controller`:

```
allObjectives: function() {
    return this.store.find('objective');
}.property()
```

Your template could then render the model as usual:

```
<div>Unit name: {{model.name}}</div>
<div>All objectives:
  <ul>
    {{#each objective in allObjectives}}
      <li>{{objective.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
```

Comment: Needed .property() at the end. Thanks for your help here!